# Oauth Causing More permissions problems

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I've been working to solve this issue for months and it is just getting worse.

I have a simple program in Google Apps script that grabs email addresses from a sheet and puts them in the appropriate Google Contacts group. It was working fine up until a month or so ago when it stopped working.

Please help me:

1) Understand If I really need to work with API's to do what I'm doing.

2) Check my work below for something I might be missing.

Original Problem:

When I run this code i get the error: "You do not have permission to perform that action."

```
function testAddEmail(){

ContactsApp.createContact(null, null, "tomfoolery@validemailaddress.com");

};
```

To resolve this issues I've:
-Made sure Contacts API is enabled in my Cloud Console.
-Disabled and reinabled it multiple times.
-Created a new file with the program and enabled new Contacts API.
-Created Credentials for the new program (It worked for one day after this).
-Contacted Google Cloud Support and G Suite Support to make sure settings are correct (they don't support script or contacts.)

Problem 2:

I've tried to add the Oauth 2 code but now it gives me the error "You do not have permission to call getActiveSpreadsheet."

Are their problems in my Oauth 2 code below? (I removed my personal info.)

```
function getContactsService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('contacts')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId('blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com')
      .setClientSecret('blablabla')

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      .setScope('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds')
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets')

      // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

      // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
      // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

      // Requests offline access.
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

Comment: Check your Apps Script manifest file - have you set scopes there? if so, they override any automatic scope detection, and are used as-is. If you don't have any scopes in the manifest file, check File->Project Properties->Scopes

Comment: "oauthScopes": [
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
     "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
     ]

Comment: The above is what I have in there now. it authorizes just fine, but doesn't let me get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you logged into multiple Google accounts? That often causes issues with authorization. Try logging out of everything and logging back in to just one account.
2. Is this running on a trigger or are you manually running the formulas?
3. Are the owner of the spreadsheet and logged in as the owner? Are you running this test in the spreadsheet's container-bound script?
4. If you're the owner of the spreadsheet and you're just adding the email addresses from your own spreadsheet to your own Gmail account then there's no reason you need to use the API or OAuth protocol.
5. As another commenter mentioned, what are the scopes you're requesting? To just set up a simple script from your spreadsheet to add contacts you probably just need the two you listed. You can set them manually by selecting view-->show manifest file. For example:

   ```
   {
      "timeZone": "America/New_York",
      "dependencies": {
        },
      "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        ]  
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this!!! 1)I've logged out of everything and am testing with only one account attached.

Comment: 2) No triggers yet. Just trying to run from Menu drop down or from within the script editor. 3) I'm the owner. This is being run on my own domain.  The script isn't shared with anyone. This is container bound. 4) I'm the owner of my domain, working with my own domain account. 5) If I don't need the API's then I don't need to worry about adding scopes. 

Any other suggestions? Should I reset GSuite Account settings to default?

Comment: I'd start over: Delete the permissions from this app by going to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and "remove access". Then comment out everything in your code (better yet, delete everything) but the test function, set the scopes explicitly in the manifest file as above, and then try to run the function from the script editor. What happens then...?

Comment: So I removed ALL the permissions from every app I have. Also opened a new sheets file and pasted in the test function above. Got the same exact error. Then I added the spreadsheet and UI scopes above. The error was specifically "You do not have permission to add contacts." So I added the contacts scope. Everything reauthorized fine again. And still got the same "You do not have permission to perform that action." Do I even need scopes though? It seems like in your comments above since it is my contacts and my script under the same email address they shouldn't.

Comment: For this new file I also went in and authorized the Contacts API

Comment: Ah my bad, I copied the wrong one -- yes the first oauthScope in the manifest file should be: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds". I wasn't able to reproduce your problem -- it worked fine for me, but I bet it's because you have a GSuite account. It looks like you might have to whitelist apps as an admin by going to  admin.google.com. Try following the steps here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227

Comment: Yes, I just got it to work fine in a different gmail account. Thanks for your help. I'll test out this whitelist business.

Comment: I whitelisted everything. Removed access from every single app to my account. removed all sharing with other users. Deleted the content of the oauth json file. removed 2 step verification and removed my 2nd email account from my chrome browser. Also went in and did security check up on this account and the other account that was connected to my browser. reauthorized program. The program is now working...FINGERS CROSSED because it usually only lasts a day when it does work. I very much appreciate your help. Will mark this as the solution if it sticks. feel free to check in to remind me. Thanks!

Comment: It only worked very briefly. It worked for me then sometime between when I fixed it and When my assistant went in there a few hours later it was broken again. assistant had his personal gmail logged into as well.

Comment: Did all the things I could with my assistant and it didn't work. Arg!!! He uses the same login as me to the same account so there shouldn't be anything different.

Comment: Maybe a cookies thing? Try in new incognito session